# Looking for a base for a constraint solving problem

Tags: optaplanner

I am new to OptPlanner but I have a reasonable understanding of constraint solving alebit somewhat dated.

I have a problem I want to model. On the one hand the National Grid have requirements to save electricity between defined time slots on specific days in specific locations (post codes). On the other individuals with static or mobile batteries charge their batteries at some point during a 24 hour cycle and have a need to get a specific amount of charge into those batteries. I need to model a set of constraints at the top (the grid) and the constraints at the bottom (the individuals) to ensure the individuals get what they need and the grid saves what it requires.

What model should I pick and why?

I am just starting this so I have not tried anything yet. I would prefer a Java/SpringBoot solution.

Many thanks for any help.

Steve T

Comment: I voted to close this question, and I feel like I should provide rationale. What you are asking is, in my opinion, not in scope of StackOverflow. Instead, domain modelling is a full-time job, requiring skills and experience. I suggest you find a consultant who will work together with you on understanding your problem and designing the appropriate model.

Answer (score 0):

First read the domain modeling guide in the docs to understand my answer below.
https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/design-patterns/design-patterns.html#domainModelingGuide

I think **the maintenance scheduling quickstart** might be a good start. Code is here:

https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/maintenance-scheduling

Motivation: it sounds like there could be gaps between charging at the charging stations, so a *chained through time* model does not fit. You're not solving a VRP anyway. So I suspect a *timegrain* model it is, which is what the maintenance scheduling quickstart actually uses.